# Anaconda Installation Issue: 'conda' Command Not Recognized and Missing Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, windows, installation, anaconda

I recently installed Anaconda on my Windows system, but I'm encountering some issues:

1. **Missing Anaconda Prompt:** After installation, I cannot find the Anaconda Prompt in the Start Menu. It seems like it wasn't installed or isn't visible.
2. **'conda' Command Not Recognized:** When I try to use conda commands in the Command Prompt, I get the error: `'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

**What I've tried:**

- I've searched online for solutions, but most require access to the Anaconda Prompt, which I don't have.
- Running `conda --` in the Command Prompt, which leads to the error
  mentioned above.
- I checked if Anaconda is installed by looking for it in the installed programs list, and it appears to be installed.
  I'm not sure if the issue is with the installation process or something else. I haven't tried modifying the environment variables yet, as I'm not certain about the correct steps to do so safely.

**Questions:**

1. How can I verify if Anaconda was installed correctly?
2. What are the correct steps to add Anaconda to the PATH environment variable in Windows, if that's the necessary solution?

Any guidance or steps to resolve these issues would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you downloaded Anaconda, but did you install it?

Answer (score -1):

Add Conda to variable path, so cmd recognizes it.

Comment: How would I add it to the variable path? I have checked online and none of the methods have worked....

Comment: You go to Control Panel\System and Security\System
Then click on Environnment variables
on System variables, scroll down until you find path, edit it, 
add semicolon then the path to the executable of conda